How to smoothly change DNS hosters without several hours of service outage?
I have recently changed my DNS hoster (again) as I needed some features which my previous DNS hoster does not provide. Everytime I changed DNS hosters my server became unavailable for several hours until DNS straightened itself out again. I know that DNS is a distributed system which caches entries for several hours, but there must be a way to change providers without service interruption.
These are the principal steps I took:

Copied over all DNS records from the previous DNS hoster to the new one.
Queried the primary DNS servers of both hosters explicitly via dig @<...> to ensure that both were identically configured
Informed my registrar about the new DNS name server and provided them with the new NS, DNSKEY and DS settings; my registrar forwarded those information to the TLD registry (in my case the .de-zone, i.e. DENIC)

Approximately one hour after I performed step 3, my servers became unavailable via DNS. DNS resolution stopped for my domain. It took approximately six more hours until everything became functional again.
Unless I am not totally mistaken, in this specific case the outage was due to a mismatch between the NS and DNSKEY records on the one hand and the DS record on the other hand during that six hours. The NS and DNSKEY records were already updated and pointed to the new DNS hoster while the DS record remained the old one for six more hours.
What is the correct approach to avoid such issues?

Addendum (2024-07-30)
Today, I wanted to migrate my second domain from the previous DNS hoster to the new DNS hoster and I thought I would be clever.
I disabled DNSSEC 48 hours in advance to avoid any signing errors. (Better to have no DNSSEC at all than a failing DNSSEC.) But then I ran into another trap.
I first configured the DNS zone information at my new DNS hoster, then told my registrar to change the NS record from the old to the new DNS hoster. However, the change was not atomic. Instead of changing the NS record from old to new they changed the NS record from the old value to the "placeholder" f.nic.de. and then from f.nic.de. to the actual new value. Those both steps were 5 minutes apart. Unfortunately, that 5 minute time window was sufficient for the Google DNS (8.8.8.8) to pick up the wrong, intermediate value f.nic.de. and it had a TTL of 14400, i.e. 4h.
Of course, f.nic.de. had no information about my actual domain. So while the error only existed for 5min, it produced another 4h DNS resolution outage on my domain for some user depending on what DNS server they queried.
By now, I believe that the hoster of my virtual private server which also "owns" my IP addresses and who is also the registrar for my domains (but not my DNS hoster), is simply stupid. They only provide a web form which allows to input an NS and a DNSKEY record. (The DS record is implicitly calculated from the DNSKEY). However, there is no option to add (or remove) records. One can only replace the existing records (one of each type). However, even if one changes both values correctly and consistently and then submits the web form, the upstream change (between my registrar and the registry) is unpredictable and out-of-order. Given the answer below, I guess there is nothing which I can do but discussing with my registrar that they must get their processes in order.

Sounds more like a mismatch between NS/DS on one side and DNSKEY on the other – even if the 'parent' asks for a DNSKEY it still converts that to DS format – but have you investigated this? (DNSViz is very useful at such checks.) Does your registrar allow more than one DS (or DNSKEY) per domain?

The addendum is not very useful to others. It doesn't help answering this question. It is not helpful to anyone that later finds this question. It is more of a complaint.

If you tell the registrar only that you need to change the DS records, they probably do exactly that. The NS and the DS records are both cached independently. No matter which one updates first on the resolver, it causes a temporary mismatch between the DS at the parent zone and the DNSKEY that signed the records at the authoritative name servers.
Multiple DS records can co-exist during the migration, so you should have asked your registrar to add the new DS records (without removing the old ones) and waited for the caches to expire before changing the NS records.

Good DNSSEC migration instructions without outages from one or two of my earlier answers:
DNSSEC migration
Normally you could just have configured DNSSEC on the new name servers and updated the DS records.  With DNSSEC, the correct order is significant! Shortened and modified a bit from Junior Payne's DNSSEC & DNS MIGRATION: How to migrate your DNS without disrupting DNSSEC:


Prepare the DNSSEC on the new provider: configure the zone and sign it.

Add DS record(s) of gaining DNS service provider and wait for TTL.
This current state will validate both the losing and gaining DNS
service providers’ ZSKs. At this point the delegation to the new name
server(s) has not yet changed. In this configuration, it’s necessary
to re-sign the zone with the gaining DNS service provider and wait for
the caches to expire (TTL of the DS records).

Change delegation of the zone to the gaining DNS service provider.

Remove DS record(s) of the losing DNS service provider
Once you are sure there are no longer any cached DS record(s)
referring to the losing DNS service provider, the losing DNS service
provider’s DS record(s) can be removed from the registry.



Erlend Eide, not recognizing this possibility, gives another path on How to Migrate Name Servers for DNS Zones with DNSSEC active. Although Junior Payne is more correct, this alternative may be the only possibility, if the new provider doesn't support configuring DNSSEC prior delegation:


Disable DNSSEC at Registrar
Wait 24 hours
Disable DNSSEC at Name Server (remove DS-records)
Switch name servers
Wait 24 hours
Re-enable DNSSEC



If you tell the registrar only [...] to change the DS records, they probably do exactly that. [...] you should have asked your registrar to add the new DS records (without removing the old ones)
Unfortunately, I cannot "ask" my registrar do to that (as ask in person), they only provide a web form which allows me to configure only the authoritative name server (NSrecord) and a DNSKEY record (the DS record is calculated from the DNSKEY automatically). There in no option to add/remove records, it is a single input field for a single record only.

I accepted this answer as the correct one, because it seems plausible. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me. See my other comment on this answer and my "addendum" to the original question. By now I am convinced that my registrar is simply stupid.

You can always switch registrars i.e. transfer the domain name.
